# Klingon evolution

Tags: star-trek, klingon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kahless and Klingon Appearance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/kahless-and-klingon-appearance)

Going from Star Trek TOS to TNG, Klingons change quite a bit. Does anyone know the explanation given for this? I know in an episode of DS9 in the trouble with tribbles flashback, Worf sort of mentions that something happened but I'm not exactly sure what it was.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20579/are-there-in-universe-explanations-for-how-some-species-apperances-change-betwe?lq=1

Comment: ST Enterprise covered this with detail, and dedicated several episodes to it.